# Watson Custom Visual Recognition in Java

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, watson, visual-recognition

I am trying to create a custom Watson Visual Recognition in java. I have already a classifier created using Curl. Currently I am using the default Watson Classifier. Are there any examples where Watson API is used for custom creation and training of classifiers in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API reference have [examples](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/?java#create_a_classifier) using java, both for creating a new classifier, update it and test it